# How to get x position of component while dragging it?

Tags: java, swing

I want get x of component which i dragged on a panel and text this bounds in JTextField so how can i do that by code ?

first i made this method to get x of component which i drag

```
  public void get_locationX (MouseEvent e)
  {
    int x = e.getComponent().getX();

    x_txt.setText(String.valueOf(x));
  }
```

and then made this event to detect when component is dragged

```
    Component[] c = design_panel.getComponents();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++)
    {
        c[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                get_locationX(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

but when i run the code and drag the component there's nothing happen

Comment: Get the location from the mouse event : `int x = e.getX();`  not from the component

Comment: @c0der i tried this but it failed also

Comment: I guess you are adding the listener to the wrong component. The mouse is not dragged over the dragged component, but on its parent. For better help post [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by coomponentListener

and this is my code after editing

```
public void get_locationX(ComponentEvent e)
{
    int x = e.getComponent().getX();

    x_txt.setText(String.valueOf(x));
}
```

and then

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++)
    {
        c[i].addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                get_locationX(e);
            }
        });
    }
```